# load TypeFace from assets and assign it to the whole application

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a large application that use a huge number of views and TextViews

I have to change the font of all these views to be a specific font

I have created a theme to assign it to the application but the font in assets folder so I have to load it then assign it

any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

One option would be to extend Activity, then extend all your activities from this. You could then write code in your base class to iterate through all the (TextView) controls on the activity. However, you might find that some of them are not accessible if they're not visible at the time.

Answer (score 0):

How about just inherit from TextView and create your own TextView that sets the typeface to the desired one?

Pro tip: Instantiate the typeface inside a singleton and you will only load it once.